# Is it possible to "Ping" other devices?

Tags: android, iphone, geolocation, ping

Is it possible for an android or iphone to recognize devices within a certain radius just for their existence? Like if I were at a coffee shop could my phone recognize that there were 12 other people there with phones? I don't really need to know much about the other devises, maybe a MAC address or something would be nice.

Comment: recongnize on basis of what? or contacts?

Comment: Ofcourse you can do this via BLE which gives rssi value in dBm. Starting Android L its even possible to talk to other ios devices also ?

Comment: I merely want to recognize on a basis of existence - whether or not they are a contact of mine, I want to know that they are there.

Vny Kumar - do you have an example of how I could use Bluetooth Low Energy to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wjholden.nmap&hl=en).